# Why doesn't my for loop find any files?

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a really simple for loop I'm trying to do in a windows CMD prompt/batch file (I've tried both with %i in command line and %%i in batch file):

```
for %%i in (workspace\*) do echo %%i
```

I wan't to display all the sub folders in a folder (just as a really simple example to get the loop working) but nothing is displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Works fine here on Windows 7. What is the output of `dir workspace`? Do you have the correct privileges on the `workspace` folder?

Comment: I'm on windows 7 too. `dir workspace` from the same command prompt outputs the list of folders I want to run the command across. This is why I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall here. This should be so simple and "just work" but it is just doing nothing.

Comment: Weird. Does: for /f "usebackq" %i in (\`dir /s/b\` ) do @echo %i work?

Comment: @DavidPostill I think it mangled the command in the comment?

Comment: Should be fixed. You need backticks \` around `dir /s/b`

Comment: If there are only directories in `workspace\ ` you need `for /d ...`.

Comment: @AFH argghg! I knew it must be something simple. That's it. I've fixed my question to clarify that. Want to post it as an answer so I can give you the internet points?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the help, turns out I'm just an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `for` displays only files, not directories, so a directory containing only subdirectories will show nothing. To show directories you need to add the `/d` option:

```
for /d %%i in (workspace\*) do echo %%i
```

This assumes the command is in a batch file (only single `%` signs if typed), and shows *only* directories. There is no option to show both: you would need to use a command such as DavidPostill suggests:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (`dir /b`) do echo %%i
```

Comment: forfiles also finds folders. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from the command prompt, and not a batch file, you need to use %i, not %%i.

Alternatively, you can use `forfiles` which has different options and may very well work a lot easier for what you need to do.

Forfiles also finds folders.